# url rewrite regex question

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

My regex expression for isapi rewrite here isn't passing variables in the URL

Trying to pass a variables like:   www.domain.com/z34232/ProductName.html?**ref=magic**

But the code is ignoring the "ref=magic" string

```
  RewriteRule .*z([[:digit:]]*)\/.*.html\??(.*)  /product.asp\?pnum=$1(?2&$2&:) [I,O,L]
```

Any suggestions would be extremely helpful. I need to keep the rest of the string intact.

Comment: Is the result supposed to be: "www.domain.com/product.asp?pnum=34232&ref=magic&:"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you trying to achieve something like this:

```
RewriteRule .*z([0-9]*)/.*\.html(\?.*)? /product.asp?pnum=$1$2 [QSA]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to pass the URL param

Comment: With QSA param it does. QSA practically means, that Apache would add query string part by its own

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the pattern to match the query string. Something similar to the following should work:

```
RewriteRule .*/z([[:digit:]]*)/.*\.html  /product.asp?pnum=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```